# Post navigation in wordpress twenty ten theme

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I am horizontally displaying twenty ten theme category posts in two columns like:

[image]

I am using below code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : 

$wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>

<div id="left-column">
<h1><?php the_permalink(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $i = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>

<div id="right-column">
<h1><?php the_permalink(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If i click on post #1 and move to single post display page, where full post displays and two links appears(next post,previous post) at top/bottom of the page. and then click on next post link it goes to display post #3. But i need to display post #2 then post #3, post#4.... how it is possible.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with css.
Use the "standard"-Loop. For example

```
<div id="main-content">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

With `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` you can control the length of the post, wordpress standard is 55 Words. So every post has a length of 55 Words.

Then you can give each .post element a width less then 50% and float it left.
An simple example:

```
#main-content {
      float: left;
}

.post {
      float: left;
      width: 42%;
      margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Now u are having two columns and you can make it responsive too and your "previous/next" links should work too.

Here is an example.
[David Hellmann](http://www.davidhellmann.com/blog/)

I hope, this can help you.
Greetings!